# mysqli mysiam select query taking too much time

Tags: mysql

i am running on php mysql server my code taking too much time as data inreasing it should not be ore than 0.01 secconds... mycode is given below the links db is mysiam engine other tables are innodb... it is search page

```
    $selecting = $db->query("

SELECT DISTINCT links.link_id AS link_id,title,description,url,fulltxt

,COUNT(links.title) AS title_count
,count
,MATCH(title) AGAINST(+'$query_star' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS weight_t
,MATCH(url) AGAINST(+'$query_star' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS weight_u
,MATCH(description) AGAINST(+'$query_star' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS weight_d
,MATCH(keywords) AGAINST(+'$query_star' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS weight_k

FROM links
INNER JOIN domains ON
url like CONCAT ('%',domain,'%')


LEFT JOIN clicks_count ON
links.link_id = clicks_count.link_id

LEFT JOIN likes ON
links.link_id = likes.link_id




WHERE (`url` LIKE '%".$domain."%') AND
MATCH(title,url,description,keywords,fulltxt) AGAINST('$query_star @50' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `active_domain` = 1
GROUP BY url

ORDER BY (weight_t+weight_u+weight_d+weight_k) DESC

LIMIT ".(($page-1)*10)." , 10

");
```

which will help me only python or is there any solution in php

Comment: Make and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` using that query to check used indexes and complexity. It probably have a poor use of indexes since you are using MATCH and LIKE. Also you should check if the LIKEd fields are indexed.

Comment: like field have only link id and no of likes.... atually i am creating a search engine.

Comment: i can remove like option but without it issue is there with increasing results excute time increases... my db have full text of a page where query is match against search words